# CSS Grid image not filling entire container

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to make an irregular grid using CSS grid, based on this codepen: https://codepen.io/jasheng/pen/BvBvPN

However, when i try to change the span values for some of the containers to be rectangles, the background color does not fill the entire container (it only fully fills the squared ones)

do you know how i can solve this? sorry if its a newbie question, it's my first time using css grids

i've tried changing every value in both .photoframe and .gallery, which is where i believe the problem lies. i've also added height:100%, object-fit: cover, and background-size: cover, to no avail.

```css
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7,auto) ;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(1,1fr);
  grid-gap: .8vw;
  width: -webkit-calc(100% );
  width: -moz-calc(100%);
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;

}

.textfield {    
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;     
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: black;
}
.textfield figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer; 
}

.textfield:hover figcaption {
    transform: all 0.8s ease-out;
    opacity: 1;
}

.photoframe {
  position: relative;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .5s ease;
    background-size: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
}
.photoframe::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
.textfield:hover .photoframe{
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.large{
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  grid-row-end: span 2; 
}
.medium{
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  grid-row-end: span 1; 
}
.small{
  grid-column-end: span ;
  grid-row-end: span 1; 
}
.large2{
  grid-column-end: span 3;
  grid-row-end: span 2; 
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">

                <div class="textfield large2">
                    <div class="photoframe" href="#"></div>
                    <figcaption>
                     </figcaption>
                </div>


                <div class="textfield small">
                    <div class="photoframe" style="" href="#"></div>
                    <figcaption>
                    </figcaption>
                </div>

                <div class="textfield small">
                    <div class="photoframe" style="" href="#"></div>
                    <figcaption>
                    </figcaption>
                </div>

                <div class="textfield large">
                    <div class="photoframe" href="#" ></div>
                    <figcaption>
                    </figcaption>
                </div>

                <div class="textfield medium">
                    <div class="photoframe" href="#"></div>
                    <figcaption>
                    </figcaption>
                </div>
```

the grid should be all yellow, without the black space we see in textfield large (the rectangle on the far right)

Comment: Codepen demo works fine (testing on Chrome). Where's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were setting the height of your `.photoframe` elements using an `::after` pseudo-element with `padding-bottom:100%`. Padding set with a percentage on the bottom or top of an element will set that padding to a percentage of the width of the element itself, not a percentage of the parent element. That is why you saw squares, the height of the elements were limited to 100% of the width, a 1:1 ratio.

I set height:100% on the .photoframe element so it fits its entire grid space.

```css
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, auto);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);
  grid-gap: .8vw;
  width: -webkit-calc(100%);
  width: -moz-calc(100%);
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.textfield {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
}

.photoframe {
  position: relative;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-size: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

.photoframe::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.textfield:hover .photoframe {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.large {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.medium {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  grid-row-end: span 1;
}

.small {
  grid-column-end: span;
  grid-row-end: span 1;
}

.large2 {
  grid-column-end: span 3;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">

  <div class="textfield large2">
    <div class="photoframe"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="textfield small">
    <div class="photoframe"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="textfield small">
    <div class="photoframe"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="textfield large">
    <div class="photoframe"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="textfield medium">
    <div class="photoframe"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```